# My ASP.NET <video> plays .webm file on FireFox plays video ok, but there is no audio

Tags: asp.net, firefox, audio, video

Audio is okay when I locally debug the Visual Basic 2013 asp.net web app project.

```
                    <video width="640"  controls="controls" preload="auto">
                    <source src="_VIDEO/<% = _video_filename %>.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                    <source src="_VIDEO/<% = _video_filename %>.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>   
                    <source src="_VIDEO/<% = _video_filename %>.webm" type="video/webm"/>
                    Your web browser fails to play our video.  <br />
                    Please try:<blockquote>
                     Upgrade your browser, or<br />
                     use a different browser, or<br />
                     Continue your application on a different computer or device. 
                        </blockquote>
                </video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  On my Windows 2008 server > IIS > MIME type > 
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
Add type video/ogg .ogv
Add type audio/ogg .oga